# Upload Image By clicking exisiting image

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple profile page which has image and some information. This profile page is filled up with the information provided during registration.

What i want is to allow registered users to click on their upload image on their profile page and be able to replace with a new one.

I know how to handle this from the database side.

I need help on the html or the front end side. In the sense that how do i make image clickable to open the upload image window.

Comment: See the accepted answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7688996/replacing-normal-file-upload-input-with-an-image

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the simplest solution to this, is to place the actual file upload element in the offset of the page and then "forward trigger" the click to it when the user clicks on the profile image.

HTML:

```
<input id="profile-image-upload" class="hidden" type="file">
<div id="profile-image">click here to change profile image</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#profile-image').on('click', function() {
    $('#profile-image-upload').click();
});
```

See my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8xCb/3/

Answer (score 1):

What have you already tried? One possible solution might be something like:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.current_image').click(function() {
   $('.new_image_box').toggle();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="/path/to/avatar.png" class="current_image" />

<div class="new_image_box">
   <input type="file" name="new_avatar"/>
</div>
```

---

If you want to avoid JavaScript and use HTML, so that users who click their existing pages get redirected away to a new page, use:

```
<a href="/upload-form">
   <img src="/path/to/avatar.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: I am new to this so this is my first time. I want the current image showing on the profile to be clickable and give me the window from which i can upload the new image.

Comment: If you just want your image to link off to a new page/window, wrap it in a `<a>` tag. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

html does not allow to skin file input, so you can not use an image as an input.

But there are some work arounds. 2 ways I know:

First one, you put a hidden file input, and trigger it when the image is clicked.

```
<img src="avatar.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="" class="myAvatar" />
<input type="file" name="newAvatar" id="newAvatar" style="display:none;" />
<script>
$(".myAvatar").click(function() {
    $("#newAvatar").trigger("click");
});
</script>
```

Second method is, you put your input in front of your image, and set its opacity to 0,

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <img src="avatar.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="" class="myAvatar" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1;" />
    <input type="file" name="newAvatar" id="newAvatar" style="width:50px; height:50px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0; z-index:2; opacity:0;" />
</div>
```

Note: There are some down sides though, first method have some issues with Internet Explorer, and if you use the second method, you cannot use mouseover events for the avatar.