# How to make a "<input type="file" />" looks like a link with CSS?

Tags: html, css

Just want to the style of:

```
<input type="file" value="Choose the file" />
```

looks like:

```
<a href="#">Choose the file</a>
```

just using css.

Is it possible?

Comment: From experience, this is a very hard element to style, particularly  in older versions of the browser.

Comment: You want to style the `file`-button as a link?

Comment: Like this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18716005/1364685

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will likely require some fine tuning for the size, hover state etc, but why not do:

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span:hover a {
  color: red;
}
a + input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<span><a href='#'>Link!</a><input type='file' /></span>
```

The basic premise is that the `input type=file` should be absolutely positioned over the link with its opacity set to zero so it still traps the normal user interaction behaviour.

Comment: Nice solution, however putting an `input` inside an `a` tag is invalid.

Comment: @putvande - absolutely, it was for demo purposes only, but have edited in the interests of accuracy :) +1

Comment: the last span shouldn't be a closing tag?

Answer (score 22):

How about using `label` instead of `anchor` and you connect the `label` with `input[type="file"]` via `for`:

```css
label{
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#file_input_id{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<label for="file_input_id">I'm a wannabe link</label>
<input type="file" id="file_input_id">
```

Note: [safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531196/unable-to-click-input-type-file-in-windows-safari-browser) has issues with using `display:none` to `input[type="file"]`

Comment: There are very clever hacks and workarounds in this thread, but this is by far the most elegant answer IMO.

Comment: I've always had problems with styling `input[type="file"]` and this solution is the best for it, IMHO.

Comment: Yeah, this is the correct answer. Sticking with form elements; clean and simple. No hacks needed.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go if you only want the appearance of a link, without any extraneous UI

Answer (score 1):

You can add a label linked to the input (and you should for accessibility anyway, especially as you really need to hide the input). Then you can set the `opacity` of the input to 0 and make it `position:absolute` so that it does not affect the page. You could hide it, but I think some browsers will not trigger the label functionality, so you won't be able to choose a file.

You can then style the label how you want, or even wrap it in an `a` tag so it will behave exactly like the other links on your page.

The disadvantage of hiding the input is that you will not be able to see the chosen file. If you need to do that you can show it in the label with a simple bit of jquery:

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function() {
  // find the label for the currrent file input 
  $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').text('Choose the file - ' + $(this).val());
});
```

```css
input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a > label {
  /* inherit the hand cursor from the a tag */
  cursor:inherit;
}

a:hover {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
    <input id="thefile" type="file" value="Choose the file" />
    <a href="#"><label for="thefile">Choose the file</label></a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this "dirty" hack:

```
input {
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: -100px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1apggx8q/

Comment: Putting an `input` inside an `a` tag is invalid.

Comment: please add some explanation to your code, showing how it solves the problem, this will help others in the future

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution similar to the above but I separate the input tag and show the link instead.

```
div.fileinputs {
    position: relative;
}

div.fakefile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
}

input.file {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  -moz-opacity:0 ;
  filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

And the html

```
<div class="fileinputs">
  <input type="file" class="file" />
  <div class="fakefile">
    <a href="">browse file</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ht8cw075/)